# How to add extra column to result by 'if'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get extra bool column to result by specific if condition
How to archive that? Here is what I can done so far, but it isn't working

```
INSERT INTO @Result 
SELECT o.ID,o.PRTableID,o.Message,o.StartTime,e.Name
FROM PROrder as o 
LEFT JOIN PREmployee as e ON o.PREmployeeID = e.ID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN @GroupId IS NULL  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END )
```

Comment: You want to execute dynamic `INSERT` query to table, marked as `@Result` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are trying to insert 0/1 into @Result table based on @GroupId value. If so, please add `Case Expression` to the `Select` list.

```
INSERT INTO @Result 
SELECT o.ID,o.PRTableID,o.Message,o.StartTime,e.Name, 
       CASE WHEN @GroupId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM PROrder as o 
     LEFT JOIN PREmployee as e ON o.PREmployeeID = e.ID
```